# How to control the crashing of my app when i switch between tabs

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have created a music application in iphone .
The App crashes if i keep on switching between the tabs while the song is playing.
How can i solve this problem .Please anybody help me regarding this problem

Comment: Please shows us the code executing during the switch and the code that start playing music.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally such kind of issues are memory related.......just check whether ur releasing the objects at proper place or not..

Other u can put some code snippet to have a look so that we can know actually what's happening with your code..

Answer (score 0):

A common cause for crashes when something repetitive happens (eg switching between tabs, screens etc) is memory problems. Make sure you are releasing the correct objects in the right place. It could very well be that every switch you are allocating objects - without freeing them when switching again. This will eventually consume your memory and crash the application.